# Radio button: event before checked prop change?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a set of radio buttons in a form. Its checked state determines the state of a large number of other inputs later down the form. If the user goes back to it after moving down the form and changes its value, I need to clear much of the form, and the user will need to reenter many values. I would like to warn them that this is going to occur. Is there an event that fires before the checked prop is changed? Or should I throw the confirm on click and if they cancel, set the value back?

To be clear, I know `.click()` fires *after* the checked property is changed. Is there an event that fires after the user clicks but before the checked property is changed?

Comment: You can use the onclick event.

Comment: please post your code and we'll try to fix it.

Comment: throw the confirm on click, and then check the result of the confirm to either clear or not...

Comment: I edited the question. I know onclick fires after the checked property is changed. Is there an event that fires after the user clicks but before the checked property is changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
<input type="radio" name="test" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure?'))event.preventDefault();" />
```

Or using JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='radio'][name='test']").click(function(e){
        if(!confirm('Are you sure?')) e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

The JQuery selector can probably be cut down to just `$("[name='test']")`. Simply change 'test' to the name of your radio button group. Also, if you want to make sure that this event fires before anything else, you might want to consider the `mousedown` event.

Comment: preventDefault works, but interestingly, there's no way of knowing whether the element is checked or not from within the click event.